# how to plot pie chart using data in pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, pie-chart

[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm relatively new to python. I want to plot a pie chart for department, i.e., how many percent of the employees coming from `Sales & Marketing`, `Operations`, `Technology`, etc...

I'm not sure how to count the total number of employees from respective department first then only fit the data into the pie chart. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the data directly instead of using an image? Also, with your sample, what is your expected output? a pie chart divided by 3:1:1 (as per the counts in `department`?)

Comment: How should I post the data directly? yes, the pie chart will be divided according to the ratio in department column

Comment: Normally, you do `print(df)` or `print(df.head())` then copy paste the result directly to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.value_counts` with `pandas.Series.plot.pie`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"department": ["Sales", "Operations", 
                                  "Sales", "Sales", "Technology"]})
df["department"].value_counts().plot.pie()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just to add to @Chris answer. If you're looking for a percentage instead of the actual value you can use this parameter `df["department"].value_counts(normalize=True)`.